# I am getting this error in magento2

Tags: magento2, error

Getting following error

> **require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: domReady!_unnormalized2**

Any help on how to fix this?

Comment: did you try loading your magento 2 on firefox?

Comment: same error in firefix

Answer (score 0):

For some reason requirejs errors like this happen to me when using grunt to dev locally, clearing magento cache after running the grunt commands fixes it for me.